# Visited Links No Longer Distinguishable

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, css

Apparently, visited links are no longer distinguishable from the rest. They used to be in a slightly different shade than non-visited ones. Personally, I found the feature to be very helpful, and I'm sure I'm not the only one. Could we please have the old feature back ? Thank you. $($I am running Windows XP SP$3$, maybe that's what's causing the problem ?$)$.

Comment: I doubt it's a problem with your computer, I see the same thing. There seem to have been a fairly update to the design of the site, many parts have been changed.

Comment: I don't think it _causes_ the problem, but running XP SP3 looks like a problem. When was XP EOLed?

Comment: If you hate it sufficiently, you can use Greasemonkey or some other extension to manually set the visited link color CSS on the site.

Comment: @AlexR: I located `all.css` in `Temporary Internet Files` and edited it manually, then copied the modified version somewhere safe for future use.

Comment: This is really bothering me now. I wish someone in the design team would fix this.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Sowing the seeds of discontent. ;-$)$

Comment: @AlexR: Can you *specifically* tell me what to write in the empty `.js` file ? Because all available solutions I've found on-line don't seem to work, for some reason...

Comment: Three months later and still no change... In case anyone is interested, installing an extension like "Stylish" or "StyleBot" and adding a custom CSS like `.question-hyperlink:visited { color: #4D7686; }` solves the problem (you can customize the color, obviously).