# Can a question's colour or background be changed if I have visited it?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, hyperlinks

Is it possible to have different colours for the questions that I have already visited, and those which I haven't?

It would be better if there is some distinction because otherwise at present, I usually end up reading the same questions again and again on the homepage.

Thanks!

Edit: At a couple of sites I visited (SO, Physics SE, Chemistry SE, Puzzling SE, Meta SE), there are different colours for the visited and un-visited questions. I am still wondering why it isn't here.

Comment: Well the text color does change from blue to purple

Comment: @Yagger I don't think it does, at least I can't see it. I've added an image for reference

Comment: It doesn't change for me either (Google Chrome in Windows 10). I've just checked. Interestingly, it does change in stackoverflow.com, but only just (from light blue to slightly darker blue).

Comment: Maybe it just works on mobile devices...

Comment: @Yagger well.. I'm on mobile, and I can't see it (Image added). Or it isn't so distinguishable (maybe).

Comment: That's weird... This is how it looks in my device https://m.imgur.com/a/OAL8r32

Comment: @Yagger The one mentioned by you is the mobile optimised version. Scroll to the bottom, and click "full site" to see the other version.

Comment: Hm.... here is a post from 2015: [Visited Links No Longer Distinguishable](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20908). I suppose the site went through some design changes since then.

Comment: Our standard is to have visited links be a different color. If that isn't the case (it doesn't seem to be) I can have the design team look at it and adjust it. This won't 100% address your request because it's cookie-based, not account-based. If you use a different computer, the links will appear unvisited again. If you want cross-system memory, I think we're unlikely to add something like that.

Comment: @Catija, do you mean browser history-based rather than cookie-based?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good question... probably? This is what happens when I try to sound too smart. ;) Whatever it is, it's not going to transfer between computers. :D

Comment: @Catija Even that would be better than having no distinction at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visited links are now a lighter shade of blue than both the unvisited and hover colors. Thanks for your patience and for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks kinda awful to me. There's too much contrast between the visited links and the non-visited links, and not enough contrast between the visited links and the background.

Comment: Can this be implemented on meta too?

Comment: At first I thought the light blue links were the unvisited links, and vice-versa. I believe most of the internet uses a darker colour for visited links. Still, a nice change.